# Compare and find Duplicated values (not entire columns) across data frame with python

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates, multiple-columns, pairwise

I have a large data frame of schedules, and I need to count the numbers of experiments run.  The challenge is that usage for is repeated in rows (which is ok), but is duplicated in some, but not all columns.  I want to remove the second entry (if duplicated), but I can't delete the entire second column because it will contain some new values too.  How can I compare individual entries for two columns in a side by side fashion and delete the second if there is a duplicate?
The duration for this is a maximum of two days, so three days in a row is a new event with the same name starting on the third day.
The actual text for the experiment names is complicated and the data frame is 120 columns wide, so typing this in as a list or dictionary isn't possible.  I'm hoping for a python or numpy function, but could use a loop.

Here are pictures for an example of the starting data frame and the desired output.[starting data frame example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vxtt.png)

[de-duplicated data frame example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMnu4.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: look at the `subset` argument in [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates is interesting, but for a data frame of this size, every row will be unique.  Plus, I don't want to drop the rows, but individual values in columns.  For me, every row is an individual piece of equipment, the duplicates from from that piece of equipment being used for multiple consecutive days for the same test.  To count the number of tests, I need the days (columns) not the rows (individual pieces of equipment) de-duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

This a hack and similar to @Params answer, but would be faster because you aren't calling `.iloc` a lot. The basic idea is to transpose the data frame and repeat an operation for as many times as you need to compare all of the columns.  Then transpose it back to get the result in the OP.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Monday':['exp_A','exp_A','exp_A','exp_A','exp_B',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'exp_D','exp_D'],
    'Tuesday':['exp_A','exp_A','exp_A','exp_A','exp_B','exp_B','exp_C','exp_C','exp_D','exp_D'],
    'Wednesday':['exp_A','exp_D',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'exp_B','exp_C','exp_C','exp_C',np.nan],
    'Thursday':['exp_A','exp_D',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'exp_C',np.nan]
    })


df = df.T

for i in range(int(np.ceil(df.shape[0]/2))):

    df[(df == df.shift(1))& (df != df.shift(2))] = np.nan
    
df = df.T
```

```
  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday
0  exp_A     NaN     exp_A      NaN
1  exp_A     NaN     exp_D      NaN
2  exp_A     NaN       NaN      NaN
3  exp_A     NaN       NaN      NaN
4  exp_B     NaN       NaN      NaN
5    NaN   exp_B       NaN      NaN
6    NaN   exp_C       NaN      NaN
7    NaN   exp_C       NaN      NaN
8  exp_D     NaN     exp_C      NaN
9  exp_D     NaN       NaN      NaN
```